# Populating ListView After SQLite Query

Tags: android, xml, listview, arraylist

I need to populate the data from the query and populate it on `ListView` with custom `Item`.

on `OnCreateView`, I'm calling my adapter like this:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stops)
```

This is my whole code of `LoadData`

```
public void LoadData() {
    String query = "SELECT ticket_placeto, COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type <> 'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Pass,\n" +
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type =  'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Baggage FROM tickets GROUP BY ticket_placeto";

    c = sqldb.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String placeto = c.getString(0);
                String passengers = c.getString(1);
                String baggages = c.getString(2);

                stops.add(placeto + "                 " + passengers + "               " + baggages);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of it

I've just hard coded the spacing on `stops.add` for temporary display of data. I already have a custom `ListItem Layout` but didn't use it for the mean time.

this is the result of the query on `chrome://inspect`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu8wH.png)

Comment: replace `ArrayAdapter` with `SimpleCursorAdapter` and you will see how your code automagically become shorter

Comment: @pskink i have tried it a while ago, but i dont know how to get the data that I've query and put it on `From` array string

Comment: After executed succesfully database query notify adapter like `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: `From` are simply column names, like "ticket_placeto", "Pass" etc

Comment: @pskink should i use the variable on the `LoadData` which im getting the `query` value? if i use directly `From` as you mentioned, no data were displayed

Comment: variable? what variable?

Comment: please take a look on the `LoadData` part. i have there `String placeto = c.getString(0)`

Comment: no, replace `void LoadData()` with `Cursor LoadData()` and use it when calling `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor

Comment: i have added screenshot of result of the query. thanks

Comment: so did you ask google for `SimpleCursorAdapter example -stackoverflow` ?

Comment: yep. but the common issue is `From` data is coming from directly to `SQLite`. my approach is after query, the `index 0`,`index 1`,`index 2`. i need to put the data on my `ListView`

Comment: you dont have to put any data: data is stored in the `Cursor` - just pass it to `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor - did you see parameters used? one of them is `Cursor` holding your data

Comment: @pskink im in the right path??. sorry first time to encounter this problem

https://ghostbin.com/paste/c5nbw

Comment: almost: `"placeto",
                "passengers",
                "baggages"` should be column names in the cursor, also your corsor needs to have `_id` column - it is required by `CursorAdapter` - simply return some `ROWID` or similar primary key

Comment: and delete `cursor.moveToFirst();` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` also if you dont know the `Cursor` content call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` method

Comment: almost get it, but where can i put this  ` String query = "SELECT ticket_placeto, COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type <> 'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Pass,\n" +
                "COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type =  'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Baggage FROM tickets GROUP BY ticket_placeto";`

Comment: where? inside `Cursor LoadData()` method

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/gtc79 on this part, i havent used my query

Comment: i think im doing it wrong on the ` adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_dispatch_list, cursor, columns, to, 0);
            lv_stops.setAdapter(adapter);` part

Comment: why you changed to `sqldb.query `? `rawQuery` was ok - just call `rawQuery` and use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` to see its data - then use those columns in `From` parameter

Comment: @pskink https://ghostbin.com/paste/apoz2 its working now, this is my final code. thanks for your help dude :)

Comment: good, isn't it now (MUCH) more simple?

Comment: yes. super simple :D

Comment: i just let my mind get tangled up by itself lol

Comment: and just cosmetics: change `columns` to `from` to be coherent with `to` and there is no need to check if `rawQuery` returns `null`: even if no data it will return empty `Cursor` - and even if you passed `null` cursor nothing would be shown

Comment: noted on this. thanks @pskink

Comment: you should put the last code snippet on answer so i can approved it as answer

Comment: its your code snippet, not mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your reference, i just re-code `LoadData`. thanks to **pskink** who help me here and to other that respond on this thread.

```
  public void LoadData() {
    String query = "SELECT _id, ticket_placeto, " +
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type <> 'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Pass," +
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type =  'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Baggage " +
            "FROM tickets GROUP BY ticket_placeto";


    final String[] columns = new String[]{
            DBHelper.TICKET_ID,
            DBHelper.TICKET_PLACETO,
            "Pass",
            "Baggage",
    };

    final int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.stops_id,
            R.id.stops_location,
            R.id.stops_passengers,
            R.id.stops_baggages
    };


    c = sqldb.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (c != null) {
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_for_stops, c, columns, to, 0);
        lv_stops.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.First initialize your List in onCreate() method of activty,

```
ArrayList<String> stops = new ArrayList<>();
```

then pass it to ArrayAdapter.

2.After successfully executing query add data to your "stops" list,then
add following line to your code.

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//to notify that your data of list has been change
```